# Angular Material Dialog moves body only in Chrome

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-material

I'm working with Angular Material (7.1.1) and when I trigger a MatDialog from a button, first of all it hide half of the page. Googling around I've found out a workaround which was to set

```
.cdk-global-scrollblock {
    position: static;
    width: initial;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

But now, every time I try to open the dialog, it opens correctly, but it scrolls the page to the top.

It only happens in Chrome 67, I already tested in Firefox 64 and it works as expected.

Any tip to help me overcome this problem is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this might be because u might not have added dialog component in entry components
in app.module.ts

```
 ........
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

  entryComponents: [
    DialogComponent <---- add your mat-dialog componet name
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, The component it's already there because the dialog opens successfully.